# Can't use method "contains" in Swift 2

Tags: swift2

I am using Swift 2.

I used this code:

```
while contains(currentCardValues, randomNumber + 1) {
```

I am getting this error:

> "contains" is unavailable: call the contains() method on the
>   sequence

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is because the `contains()` method is defined in a protocol extension of `Sequence`.
So you should call it this way:

```
currentCardValues.contains(randomNumber + 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Please check this code:

```
    let array = [34, 56, 76, 77, 75]
    if array.contains(34) {
        print("contains")
    }else {
        print("Not Contains")
    }
```

Here contains() returns **bool** value