# Value of type PFObject has no member after updating to Xcode 7

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2, xcode7

After I updated Xcode to 7.0 (and Swift 2.0) my app no longer accepts one of my Parse statements. I have a standard Parse query. Within that query I have the following block of code:

```
for user in users! {
                            if !contains(accepted, user.username) && !contains(rejected, user.username){

                                self.usernames.append(user.username)
                                self.users.append(user as! PFUser)

                                if let data = user["image"] as? NSData {
                                    self.userImages.append(data)
                                }
                            }
```

I get the following error on `user.username` in the code above:

`Value of type 'PFObject' has no member 'username'`

I tried removing/readding the Parse SDK but no luck. I even edited the PFObject.h header file (a solution I found on another SO post) but that didn't work either. Any ideas? Did Parse SDK implementation change with Xcode 7? Am I missing something?

Thanks!!

EDIT: gist of full code:
https://gist.github.com/jtansley/6c2bb4b8cb82459b8c10

Comment: Seems like your `users` is a collection of `PFObject`s and not `PFUser`s

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I initialized the collection as PFUser. How can I fix this? Not sure why it sees this as PFObject. See full gist here: https://gist.github.com/jtansley/6c2bb4b8cb82459b8c10

Comment: I'm not an expert on Swift, but see if my answer below helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
if let users = users as? [PFUser] {
  for user in users {
    ...
  }
}
```

UPDATE:

Something like the following:

```
if !accepted.contains(user.username) && !rejected.contains(user.username)
```

Comment: I think this might be working, not sure. I'm getting a new error on line ` if !contains(accepted, user.username!) && !contains(rejected, user.username!)`. I get error `'contains' in unavailable: call the 'contains()' method on the sequence`. Any idea what this means?

Comment: Tried to change it to `user.contains(accepted, user.username)` after looking at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30839733/cant-use-contains-in-swift2-using-xcode-7 but still no luck, says PFUser has no member 'contains'

Comment: `Cannot invoke 'contains' with an argument list of type ([String],String)'`. I'll accept this answer because I think you fixed the original issue. Just seems like now I'm uncovering more and more issues with outdated code now that Xcode 7 is out

Comment: Seems like you are passing two parameters to the `contains` function. See update to my answer.